# eslintrc.js:4 "parserOptions": { ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 2

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, eslint

/* eslint disable */
{

"parserOptions": {
"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
"requireConfigFile": false, // <== ADD THIS
"ecmaVersion": 2018, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
"sourceType": "module", // Allows for the use of imports
"babelOptions": {
"presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
}
},
"root": true,
"plugins": ["promise"],
"extends": "eslint:recommended",
"rules": {
// Removed rule "disallow the use of console" from recommended eslint rules
"no-console": "off",

```
// Removed rule "disallow multiple spaces in regular expressions" from recommended eslint rules
"no-regex-spaces": "off",

// Removed rule "disallow the use of debugger" from recommended eslint rules
"no-debugger": "off",

// Removed rule "disallow unused variables" from recommended eslint rules
"no-unused-vars": "off",

// Removed rule "disallow mixed spaces and tabs for indentation" from recommended eslint rules
"no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": "off",

// Removed rule "disallow the use of undeclared variables unless mentioned in /*global */ comments" from recommended eslint rules
"no-undef": "off",

// Warn against template literal placeholder syntax in regular strings
"no-template-curly-in-string": 1,

// Warn if return statements do not either always or never specify values
"consistent-return": 0,

// Warn if no return statements in callbacks of array methods
"array-callback-return": 1,

// Require the use of === and !==
"eqeqeq": 2,

// Disallow the use of alert, confirm, and prompt
"no-alert": 2,

// Disallow the use of arguments.caller or arguments.callee
"no-caller": 2,

// Disallow null comparisons without type-checking operators
"no-eq-null": 2,

// Disallow the use of eval()
"no-eval": 2,

// Warn against extending native types
"no-extend-native": 1,

// Warn against unnecessary calls to .bind()
"no-extra-bind": 1,

// Warn against unnecessary labels
"no-extra-label": 1,

// Disallow leading or trailing decimal points in numeric literals
"no-floating-decimal": 2,

// Warn against shorthand type conversions
"no-implicit-coercion": 1,

// Warn against function declarations and expressions inside loop statements
"no-loop-func": 1,

// Disallow new operators with the Function object
"no-new-func": 2,

// Warn against new operators with the String, Number, and Boolean objects
"no-new-wrappers": 1,

// Disallow throwing literals as exceptions
"no-throw-literal": 2,

// Require using Error objects as Promise rejection reasons
"prefer-promise-reject-errors": 2,

// Enforce “for” loop update clause moving the counter in the right direction
"for-direction": 2,

// Enforce return statements in getters
"getter-return": 2,

// Disallow await inside of loops
"no-await-in-loop": 2,

// Disallow comparing against -0
"no-compare-neg-zero": 2,

// Warn against catch clause parameters from shadowing variables in the outer scope
"no-catch-shadow": 1,

// Disallow identifiers from shadowing restricted names
"no-shadow-restricted-names": 2,

// Enforce return statements in callbacks of array methods
"callback-return": 2,

// Require error handling in callbacks
"handle-callback-err": 2,

// Warn against string concatenation with __dirname and __filename
"no-path-concat": 1,

// Prefer using arrow functions for callbacks
"prefer-arrow-callback": 1,

// Return inside each then() to create readable and reusable Promise chains.
// Forces developers to return console logs and http calls in promises.
"promise/always-return": 2,

//Enforces the use of catch() on un-returned promises
"promise/catch-or-return": 2,

// Warn against nested then() or catch() statements
"promise/no-nesting": 1
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I change .eslintrs.js into .eslintrc.json solved the issue